# I have a UX related question but its more technical than fundamental - Where should I ask?

Tags: discussion

I have a question which is basically: "Users want local movie theater schedules to show up when they ask Siri about movies, how does a theatre make their schedules available to Siri?"

This is involves UX but its mostly a tech question. I haven't found any answer on Google. Can anyone suggest an SE site where I can ask this? Is there any site covering the subject?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.

I think the best place would be on the [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.